# Forcing download of an mp3 using header and readfile

Tags: php, file-io, download, mp3

I'm in the middle of making a backing track website. I'm using a separate download.php that checks if you're logged in and own the track and then using header() and readfile() to (attempt to) download it. The problem is that it's returning a weird error like it's literally reading the text version of the file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8w0i.png

Here's the code, as the code option on the site seems to be bugging (all relevant code is at the bottom, and ignore the jargon of $file it's pretty necessary to make downloading work for all of the tracks.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngxvy.png

P.S. I've checked about 10 existing stackoverflow questions but none have got the error I'm getting, so the solutions have not helped

Edit:
Clicking the download arrow runs this javascript function. I'm not sure if the problem is that there might be a header overlap of some kind?

```
function link(x) {
var y = $("#transpose"+x).val();
xmlhttp.open('POST','download.php',true); 
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send('y='+y+'&x='+x);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any error. Are you using javascript to load the mp3 and display it in an alarm?

Comment: The alert in the first picture is the error, the track should be downloading as an mp3 but instead it's displaying that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `mime_content_type` issue , check with different server and btw mime_content_type deprecated [check this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php).
Or try to put some static file and check.

Comment: Hey, I'm not using mime_content_type anywhere in the website

Comment: I would suggest try that and see.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean haha, how can it be a mime_content_type issue if I haven't used that function anywhere?